Middleware is not working in NextJs 15 even after using middleware.js file system?
I am new to Next.js and am trying out its middleware, which I created in the main directory (project/middleware.js). The login route is located at (project/src/app/api/login/route.js). However, I’m not seeing any console output in the terminal when I send a request through Postman. Is there something I might be missing?
import dbConnect from "@/app/(backend)/lib/DbConnect";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req) {
  console.log("hell world");
  return NextResponse.next();
}

// Optionally, define specific paths for API routes
export const config = {
    runtime: "nodejs",
  matcher: "/api/login",
};


This question is similar to: NextJS middleware does not seem to be triggered. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
